# Laravel/Vagrant and Gulp: CSS and JavaScript files seem to get cached somewhere

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, gulp, vagrant

I recently started developing in Laravel but quickly ran into a problem with using Gulp and Vagrant. The problem is that when I compile my SCSS (SASS) to css, the browser doesn't seem to update the css file. The file is getting properly synced in vagrant and does not get cached by NGINX. I know this because I disabled caching on the server side and checked the synced-folder /var/www/my-project/public/css folder to see if the file got correctly compiled.

The file only correctly loads when I reload the vagrant box, which is weird as the synced-folder shows the correctly compiled file on the server. Clearing cache in the browser does not help. I have no idea where the problem lies. I use Google Chrome.

Below my server block and Gulpfile:

NGINX server-block (note that this is not Laravel homestead):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, $date, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task("sass", function () {
    gulp.src(path.sass.src)
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                this.emit("end");
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.sass.destination))
        .pipe(notify({
            message: "Sass compiled.",
            onLast: true
        }));
});
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work :( @JPark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution has been found!**

Find the spot in your assorted nginx config files that says `sendfile on` and change it to `sendfile off`.

Sendfile is used to ‘copy data between one file descriptor and another‘ and apparently has some real trouble when run in a virtual machine environment, or at least when run through Virtualbox. Turning this config off in nginx causes the static file to be served via a different method and your changes will be reflected immediately and without question.

Source: https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/